# Conditional wp_enqueue_script on a page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, actions

For efficiency we are trying to hook some JS scripts only a certain page template of a theme that is to hold a form:  page-with-form.php

On the theme functions.php we've defined a init_method as such:

```
function my_init_method(){

    $dir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/js/jquery.js";
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery',$dir);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    $dir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/js/jquery.validate.min.js";
    wp_deregister_script('jquery.validate.min');
        wp_register_script('jquery.validate',$dir);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.validate.min');

    $dir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/js/funcion.js";
    wp_deregister_script('funcion');
        wp_register_script('funcion',$dir);
    wp_enqueue_script('funcion');
}
```

We then expected we could just add at the firts line of page-with-form.php page template (before get_header()) :

```
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

- Is this not possible?
- Are we forced to add an if rule to the functions.php function to detect that we are on that page?

***Code modifications based on answers:***
On the page template load the function directly, no need to add_action("init"...

```
my_init_method();
...
get_header();
```

Comment: For clarification, because i believe responders may have overlooked this point in your question. Are you referring to running the above code on a page that has a specific **page template** attached to it? (that's how i read the opening part of your question). In that case it would probably be more ideal to use `is_page_template()` in place of `is_page()` ...

Comment: yes, either way would work but I was refering to page_template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`init` is much earlier than page template loading and not appropriate place for enqueues (despite many tutorials and docs using it for that).

Hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and make sure you are doing that hooking before `wp_head()` call in template.

Comment: Understood now that the page-template is too late for init action and what you meant was call a personalized function. We've now just called my_init_method() as such with no init action and it works. Other alternatives to load conditionally if the page or page_template should also work but we have not tested them.

Comment: @luison Just hooking function in template will work, but as per my answer it is best practice to hook enqueues to `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: And the point being, you can call `is_page_template()` inside the callback on `wp_enqueue_scripts` and get the correct return value(true/false), where as init would have been too early to call `is_page_template()` or the like. Just clarifying incase it's not clear.

Comment: I'm going to update the `wp_enqueue_scripts` codex entry today, about time those bad examples were replaced(since it's encouraging users to enqueue on init).

Comment: @t31os looking forward to it! I am mostly busy [creating missing pages for function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Special:Contributions/Rarst) lately, so no resolve left for editing. :)

Comment: I'll let you know when i'm done on my first draft(i'm not the best person for writing docs), will appreciate some feedback on what can be done to improve it once i've finished up.

Comment: [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:T31os/wp_enqueue_script-draft) for now, need more time to work on it further.

Answer (score 3):

When you loaded your template file, you already passed the `'template_redirect'` hook, which is too late (See: [Plugin/Action API Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)).

You need to set the `add_action` call in your functions.php file, which is loaded before the `after_setup_theme` hook - which is the first available hook for themes.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using the correct hook (as pointed out by @Rarst), you will need to move your functional code to `functions.php`, and wrap the function contents in an `if ( is_page( 'page-with-form' ) )` conditional.

Comment: Moving to `functions.php` not really required. If it's more convenient to keep this in template there is no issue with that.

Comment: I disagree. for various reasons, function definitions belong in `functions.php`.

Comment: I am merely stating technical nuance, not claiming that everything in template would be best practice. Also as per original question function definition itself **is** in `functions.php`, they only want hook directive in template (which is just fine as for me).

Comment: I should have clarified: the OP states that the `add_action()` call is in the *template file*; that's the one that should be moved to `functions.php`. But even WRT technical nuance, the template loads at a different point in the execution from when `functions.php` loads, so adding `add_action()` calls in the template file might not work, from a *technical* perspective, depending on what hook is being called.

Comment: I disagree that `add_action()` **must** be in `functions.php`. Even though it is common (and good) practice it is not always possible/desireable/easy to have all adds centralized. I mentioned in my answer that it should be put before `wp_head()` call if kept in template.